# GTest - Pass Mock function parameter to ASSIGN()

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

So i have a function lets say WriteHW(value) that normally writes to a hardware UINT32 but i am mocking.  I want to get the input passed to that mock function, and pass it to an ASSIGN action to assign that value to a local variable to the test itself.  That way i can validate that the value being written(usually through bit manipulation) is correct, sort of emulating the hardware storage.

So my parameter 4 is an input that gets "written" to my mock hardware (regStorage variable).
Basically my Mock expect looks like this

```
EXPECT_CALL(cAdapterMock, ReadByPort(_, _, _, _, _))              
        .Times(1)
        .WillRepeatedly(DoAll(::testing::Assign(&regStorage, WHAT-DO-I-PUT-HERE-TO-GET-ARG4-THAT-CAME-INTO-READ-BY-PORT),::testing::Return(0)));
```

I am trying to figure out how i get the arg4 that came into ReadByPort so i can put it in the second parmeter of Assign to get it put in regStorage.

I've had success using an ACTION macro to get the arg4 value, but that seems really stupid mechanic so i assume there has to be an easier way.

```
ACTION(GetWrittenMauiRegister) { return arg4; }
EXPECT_CALL(cAdapterMock, ReadByPort(_, _, _, _, _))              // #3
            .Times(1)
            .WillRepeatedly(DoAll(::testing::Assign(&regStorage, (UINT32)GetWrittenMauiRegister),::testing::Return(0)));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One was is to use Invoke.. As mentioned in [GMOCK - how to modify the method arguments when return type is void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092758/gmock-how-to-modify-the-method-arguments-when-return-type-is-void/46094039#46094039)

```
ProxyReadByPort(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {
   ::testing::Assign(...., arg2);
   return 0;
}

EXPECT_CALL(cAdapterMock, ReadByPort(_, _, _, _, _)
   .WillOnce(Invoke(ProxyReadByPort))
```

BTW, Times(1) and WillRepeatedly() works however is not nice, use WillOnce instead.

Comment: Hmm, i was hoping there was some direct way without needing to write an seperate method or macro that i was missing from the google mock cheat sheet.  Its almost easier just to have ACTION macros for say arg0 through arg4 if your answer really is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution is using SaveArg(pointer) where N is the argument and pointer is the variable you want to save the argument too.